# Comparing two nested integer arrays in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

When migrating to Swift 3, my comparison of two nested integer arrays failed with an error, so I implemented an ugly workaround - see below.
There has to be a better way to do this ...

```
Import Foundation

var n1 = Array<Array<Int>>()
var n2 = Array<Array<Int>>()

var arraysAreEqual: Bool

// This does not work anymore in Swift 3
if n1 == n2 { // error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied
    //           to two 'Array<Array<Int>>' operands
    arraysAreEqual = true
} else {
    arraysAreEqual = false
}

// Workaround
if n1.count == n2.count {
    arraysAreEqual = true
    for i in 0 ..< n1.count {
        if n1[i] != n2[i] {
            arraysAreEqual = false
        }
    }
} else {
    arraysAreEqual = false
}
```

Comment: @Hamish: Actually it does compile in Swift 2 as I just verified. But only if Foundation is imported, so I assume that some automatic conversion to NSArray is done.

Comment: @MartinR correct - Foundation was imported (added this to the code snippet)

Comment: You  would get the old behaviour with an explicit conversion: `if n1 as NSArray == n2 as NSArray {...}` (which was done in Swift 2 automatically if needed).

Comment: ... However, that means that each inner array is "wrapped" into an *object.*

Comment: @MartinR Ah interesting, didn't know that the implicit bridge worked for multidimensional arrays – thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MartinR nice! Bridging doesn't seem to be desired though, performance wise. I am still wondering if this is a missing feature or if there is a reason that this does not work out-of-the box ...

Comment: @Jekapa: Making arrays of `Equatable` elements conform to `Equatable` itself is planned for Swift 4: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md.